# Whatsap not detecting phone local backup of chats when reinstalling whatsap

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore, android-device-manager

I am hoping you can help me.

I had WhatsApp version 2.21.8.17 on my POco F3 phone, it stopped working and has never backed up WhatsApp chats to Google drive, so I was forced to update the whattsapp to new version  2.22.2.73.

I backed up chats to phone local backup.

When I reinstalled the new WhatsApp it is not prompting to restore from local backup, and searching Google drive in which I have no backup.

I have looked in file manager, WhatsApp, databases and see the backup file mgstor.db.crypt14, and a few more files with dates. Do i have to do anything specific to the files, move them to different location so whatsapp detects it?

Why is WhatsApp not picking this local backup up when I login and verify my Number on WhatsApp.

From watching youtube videos looks simple and whatsap should restore from backup file from the phone, but it is not and not even attempting this step, and ask to check google drive where nothing is backed up.

CAN ANYONE HELP?

Comment: Since Poco F3 runs on Android 11, there's a change in the location. Please look at the answers on the duplicate.

Comment: Hi Andrew how do I contact you, I not to good with IT